# Set library path for installing unicorn using pip on macOS (libunicorn.dylib is missing)

Tags: python, macos, pip

I want to install Python unicorn on macOS Mojave using `python` (2.7) and `pip`.

I've already compiled `libunicorn.dylib` from source, which can be seen below:

```
Nicolass-MacBook-Pro:Tools nlykkei$ sudo find / -iname libunicorn.dylib 2>/dev/null
/usr/local/lib/libunicorn.dylib
```

When I attempt to install Python unicorn, I get the below error, namely that `libunicorn.dylib` cannot be found. How can I make it so that `pip` uses libraries in `/usr/local/lib`?

```
Nicolass-MacBook-Pro:Tools nlykkei$ UNICORN_QEMU_FLAGS="--python=/opt/local/bin/python" pip install unicorn
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting unicorn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/7f/47fe864fe967e91de2d57677618cffc91bee3918f0a3cdbaa6500b36855e/unicorn-1.0.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: unicorn
  Building wheel for unicorn (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qg/d7f5_p4j1px1gqb9c3xxl80w0000gn/T/pip-install-5zSTD0/unicorn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/qg/d7f5_p4j1px1gqb9c3xxl80w0000gn/T/pip-wheel-5V3QqP --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Building C extensions
  cd qemu && \
    ./configure --cc="cc" --extra-cflags="-DUNICORN_HAS_X86 -DUNICORN_HAS_ARM -DUNICORN_HAS_ARMEB -DUNICORN_HAS_M68K -DUNICORN_HAS_ARM64 -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPS -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPSEL -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPS64 -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPS64EL -DUNICORN_HAS_SPARC -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -m32 -arch i386 -m64 -arch x86_64" --target-list="x86_64-softmmu, arm-softmmu, armeb-softmmu, m68k-softmmu, aarch64-softmmu, mips-softmmu, mipsel-softmmu, mips64-softmmu, mips64el-softmmu, sparc-softmmu,sparc64-softmmu," --python=/opt/local/bin/python

  ERROR: pthread check failed
         Make sure to have the pthread libs and headers installed.

  make: *** [qemu/config-host.h-timestamp] Error 1
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libunicorn.dylib'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for unicorn
  Running setup.py clean for unicorn
Failed to build unicorn
Installing collected packages: unicorn
  Running setup.py install for unicorn ... error
    Complete output from command /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qg/d7f5_p4j1px1gqb9c3xxl80w0000gn/T/pip-install-5zSTD0/unicorn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/qg/d7f5_p4j1px1gqb9c3xxl80w0000gn/T/pip-record-iBB9QD/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    Building C extensions
    cd qemu && \
        ./configure --cc="cc" --extra-cflags="-DUNICORN_HAS_X86 -DUNICORN_HAS_ARM -DUNICORN_HAS_ARMEB -DUNICORN_HAS_M68K -DUNICORN_HAS_ARM64 -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPS -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPSEL -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPS64 -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPS64EL -DUNICORN_HAS_SPARC -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -m32 -arch i386 -m64 -arch x86_64" --target-list="x86_64-softmmu, arm-softmmu, armeb-softmmu, m68k-softmmu, aarch64-softmmu, mips-softmmu, mipsel-softmmu, mips64-softmmu, mips64el-softmmu, sparc-softmmu,sparc64-softmmu," --python=/opt/local/bin/python

    ERROR: pthread check failed
           Make sure to have the pthread libs and headers installed.

    make: *** [qemu/config-host.h-timestamp] Error 1
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libunicorn.dylib'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qg/d7f5_p4j1px1gqb9c3xxl80w0000gn/T/pip-install-5zSTD0/unicorn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/qg/d7f5_p4j1px1gqb9c3xxl80w0000gn/T/pip-record-iBB9QD/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/qg/d7f5_p4j1px1gqb9c3xxl80w0000gn/T/pip-install-5zSTD0/unicorn/
```

Comment: https://github.com/unicorn-engine/unicorn/issues/1075

Comment: @phd - how can I edit makefile when using pip?

Comment: https://github.com/unicorn-engine/unicorn/tree/master/bindings/python

Comment: @phd - it worked! THANK YOU. But why didn't it work with `pip`? Was it because `pip` attempted to install old unicorn source code that had not been fixed? (issue 1075 clearly states that newer versions of unicorn has fixed the problem).

Comment: *`pip` attempted to install old unicorn?* Yes, I think so. The current [unicorn at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/unicorn/1.0.1/#history) is version 1.0.1 released in 2017.

Comment: @phd - Not to bother you, but how do you actually check what version of unicorn comes with `pip` from the terminal? Is it only checkable through your PyPI website? Furthermore, I would gladly accept your comments as an answer :-)

Comment: Yes, PyPI is the authoritative source of information. You can try to see the version before installing with `pip search unicorn` but the results only include version, not date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that module [unicorn at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/unicorn/1.0.1/#history) is rather old — version 1.0.1 was released at 31-05-2017 while the code in the [repository](https://github.com/unicorn-engine/unicorn) is fresh.

Clone the repository and install with commands:

```
cd bindings/python
sudo python setup.py install
```

This will build the core C library and the python bindings. See instructions at https://github.com/unicorn-engine/unicorn/tree/master/bindings/python